# Why does editing another user's post result in an error message?

Tags: bug, edits

I want to edit another user's post as it is grammatically incorrect.
When only fixing spelling errors in the body and title I am getting the error

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Is this expected behaviour?
Why would I, as an editor be able to add technical details to a post I didn't make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). It's either an old post from before the quality checks were introduced, or it's posted by someone with more reputation than you (reputation level has some effect on what you can post and what not). The system can't see you didn't add/change any code without doing an entire diff operation (and even that sometimes fails to yield the proper results). It simply looks at the entire body of text you're trying to submit.

In those cases, it's best to leave the post alone; while your changes may be an improvement to the post, it's likely not enough to remove it from low quality territory. Your efforts are better spent on other posts.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, the user who posted the question has less reputation than I do.
However, it was edited by another user with more reputation than me right before I wanted to edit the question.
So I assume, that's the reason why it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, that seems likely.

Comment: Do we have any doc on where the cut-off reputation is for those quality checks on posts? I recall I hit one on a site I only had the association bonus so it must be higher then that.